# Fermi surface and its realisation

Tags: condensed-matter

Fermi surfaces are constructions in $k$-space, then how do we realise it in a diagram in the real space. I have seen diagrams where we represent fermi surfaces on a crystal surface.[image]

Comment: What is a *diagram* for you please ? Your question is not that clear unfortunately. Maybe you can provide one example of such *diagram*, that would help understanding your question.

Comment: I have attached the image.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Are you sure this is a picture of the crystal lattice ? Isn't it a Wigner-Seitz unit cell in the reciprocal space instead ? Then everything is in the momentum space, and everything is consistent.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but if its a weigner-seitz cell then its ok